# Why do Spot Instances(EC2) change from cancelled_terminating to cancelled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deep-learning, amazon-iam

I have been struggling with this since last 2 days - 
A. Trying to create AWS Spot Instance with Deep Learning AMI for Linux (free).
B. Upon launching EC2 Instance it says Spot Instance request successfully created but it fails to create the instance. 
C. Using Spot Fleet role, and later have been trying to change it to provide Admin access to this role through Policies.

However, the instance is never created and in the History tab I see Event Type = fleetRequestChange goes from **Submitted**, **active**, **cancelled_terminating** within a minute and later **cancelled**.

I have been reading through its documentation but don't see a reason for it to fail. Verified the Region and AMI as well. Tried changing bid price and with default recommended option as well. But nothing seems to work.

This is the link I'm referring - [AWS setup for Deep Learning](https://chatbotslife.com/aws-setup-for-deep-learning-fda04db6df75)

Please skip the initial portion of getting credits and you can directly jump to EC2 instance configuration setup.

Kindly help! I am unable to proceed for the past 2 days.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It worked perfectly fine for me.**

- Launched the **Deep Learning AMI** (ami-df77b6a7) in the Oregon region
- Spot pricing as documented in the article you referenced
- I could ssh into the instance after it launched

One thing you could check... Click the **Limits** link in your EC2 console to confirm that you can launch this type of instance.

Mine said:

- Running On-Demand g2.2xlarge instances: **5**

Comment: Thank You John. I checked the Limits and it says 0 for g2.2xlarge instance.

I didn't know this was the issue since the error I got didn't say anything about it. Thank you so much! :) I have requested to increase the instances to 2 since I'm working on my school project, I don't think I will be needing more.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Hey John, did you change the Price above On-Demand price? I have bid for high price than On-Deman still it's failing. AWS alloted me two instances limit.

Comment: You can check the current price by clicking the **Pricing History** button. Spot price varies by instance type, availability zone and operating system. Try other AZs/regions if the price is too high.

Comment: I could work on regular EC2 instances but not spot instances. I checked the pricing history and bid price above the regular price depending on the time of the day but in vain. AWS has forwarded my request to an account specialist to look into Spot instances issue. Shouldn't be a big thing, I suppose, since I could launch regular instances. Thanks for all your help!